# Microsoft Coded UI Test takes exteremly long time to refresh page with cascading dropdowns

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests, cascadingdropdown

Unfortunately I cannot post any source code but I've seen this behavior on multiple websites.

I have a page that contains 3 drop downs.  The first drop down will populate the second, the second populating the third.

Each drop down initiates a post-back.  While regularly navigating the site, it works extremely fast, without a hitch.  However, with the Coded UI test, it takes an extremely long time to load the page after making each selection.  I'm guessing since the page post-back, there's some *stuff* the test must do before continuing.

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think this behavior occurs because `CodedUI Tests` are collecting many data from the pc they are executed.

I suggest you to disable all `Data and Diagnostics`, by [editing the TestSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256991%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#CreateLocal) file.

Then, if your tests are running faster try to find the balance between the Data you want to collect and the test's optimization.

Comment: I think that's a great suggestion.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!

Comment: Schaliasos - Unfortunately I don't have anything enabled under Data & Diagnostics.  Any other recommendations?